# Vega-Lite layered chart: how to get tick marks and tick labels to span the entire axis?

Tags: vega-lite

I am working on a layered chart where I have both bars and rule lines. The issue I'm having is that on the x-axis, the tick marks and tick labels only appear under the bars and do not span the entire axis, making it so that there are no tick marks and labels underneath where the rule lines are located. Here is an example of what I'm seeing ([link to Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "transform": [
  {"calculate": "2*datum.IMDB_Rating", "as": "UpperLimit"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"bin": true, "field": "IMDB_Rating", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "max",
          "field": "UpperLimit",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {"value": "red"},
        "size": {"value": 5}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1sMl.png)

How do I get the tick marks and labels to span the entire axis? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

When you use a bin transform within an encoding, Vega-Lite adjusts the default axis properties to match the binning. You can re-adjust these manually via the encoding's `scale` and `axis` properties, but I think a simpler way is to move the bin transform to the chart's `transform` specification. Here is an example ([Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5gkVgCcx2LTvSlU3Co2Sx5ilQF91ESHiPolsAGbcjVDMAbQ0IA3h0MXhWMR1kM0gAJgAqbTxWVDoASQBZABEAIQB9ACUdRiVqNSh0WESAVUJCZCMAGUZUZkhXMLBQCEGodkqzT1ZkNyGoXzsxTUS8orKKqrU+9zqQyCWS8rxK6mKABhqdgr3Vo4BGSABdPucNO6nIOIBPVpC+genIDCMAGtEux0EZ1tMoMglPBuJpDmZfpDIAAPREbP6zZDzRYXFYHKonCGQwYed4tRIAR1Y3gOugOVGJJOGoxwkBGSiUyAWGIgvWZqKSiMgWJxbN2+MOxVu-JJkHewvQ1GoRmEeASbNhrCUeDOeHJGqg1NpzAqjKekItg1l4Qx-zBwLZRliCSmQ0g0Nh8LW+l5UDRvuZm2Vqto6sSGDRbrlooWbKaLXanW60eR+opbONOtNDISfptf1hYgCwooUQmiVVCwL7tgjAAXoaDGWxBWcABWK1DLtgK0PZxAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/movies.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "2*datum.IMDB_Rating", "as": "UpperLimit"},
    {
      "bin": true,
      "field": "IMDB_Rating",
      "as": ["IMDB_Rating_0", "IMDB_Rating_1"]
    }
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "IMDB_Rating_0",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "bin": "binned"
        },
        "x2": {"field": "IMDB_Rating_1"},
        "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "max",
          "field": "UpperLimit",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {"value": "red"},
        "size": {"value": 5}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could explain how to re-adjust it manually via the encoding's scale and axis properties? I'm using a more complicated example using aggregated ElasticSearch data in Kibana, and I having trouble getting things to work when I move the binning into the transform spec. So I'd like to try adjusting the scale / axis properties instead. Thank you very much!

Comment: I should also mention, we are using Kibana 6.8.0, which only supports Vega-Lite v2 or Vega v4.